# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, router

**"next": "13.0.7"**
**pages version**

I've got this error in console production mode :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
```

while this message shows on the screen :

```
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
```

I can't find the problem

this is how I used router :

```
    import React from 'react';
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {ALL_VENDORS, PANEL, PUBLIC_PANEL, SIGNAL, VENDORS} from "/navigation/CONSTANS";
import {useRouter} from "next/router";

const Item = () => {
    const {myService} = useSelector(state => state.service);
    const [openBuy, setOpenBuy] = React.useState(false);

    const router = useRouter();

    console.log("test:", router)

    const changePage = () => {
        if (router.isReady)
            router.push((myService.service_owner?.id === detail.service_owner?.id)
                ?
                `${PANEL}${SIGNAL}`
                :
                `${PUBLIC_PANEL}${VENDORS}/${detail?.id}/${detail.service_owner?.id}`)
    };


    return (
        <>
           <div onClick={changePage}>check</div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Item;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: As evident in the error message, somewhere in the function you have passed to a `map` method of an array, you are attempting to call `push` method on a array reference which is `undefined`. Find and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

try taking this piece of your code

```
router.push((myService.service_owner?.id === detail.service_owner?.id)
                ?
                `${PANEL}${SIGNAL}`
                :
                `${PUBLIC_PANEL}${VENDORS}/${detail?.id}/${detail.service_owner?.id}`)
```

and making it into a function like

```
if("logic"){
router.push("certain-link");
}else{
router.push("certain-link");
}
```

and see if this works or if the error u get still persists

Comment: That `push` is okay as `router` is guarantied to not be `undefined` by the `if` statement.